# What is the correct way to change FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE in django?

Tags: django, django-file-upload

If I change FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE, do I have to change DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE as well?

Django default:

```
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2.5 Mb
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2.5 Mb
```

My api expects two files in a json request. Storing these files on disk is not an option. I have to work on these files in memory.

Should I just update FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE to 3Mb? Or should I change DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE to 8.5 Mb? Or should I change FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE to 3Mb and DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE to 8.5 Mb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only change the `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` because `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` doesn't affect file uploads as you can read in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-memory-size) :

> The check is done when accessing request.body or request.POST and is
> calculated against the total request size excluding any file upload
> data.